# Custom Case Comment Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

Can anybody please help me to fetch Case fields(Subject and Description) from case to case comment for a visual force page as I am trying to create custom visual force page for Case Comment

below is my code so far

```
                 <!--     <apex:outputField  value="{!Case.Subject}" label="Subject"/>
                      <br></br>
                      <apex:outputField   label="Description"/>
                      <br></br>     -->

                  </apex:pageBlockSection>

                  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Comment Details" columns="2"  collapsible="false">

                        <apex:inputField value="{!CaseComment.IsPublished}"  label="Public"/>
                        <br></br>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox label="Send Customer Notification"/>
                        <br></br>
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!CaseComment.CommentBody}"  label="Comment" required="true" style="width:550px; height:125px;"/>

                  </apex:pageBlockSection>

                               <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton value="Check Spelling"/>
                                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                         </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go via the `Parent` field that relates `CaseComment` to `Case`. So, the subject would be `{!CaseComment.Parent.Subject}`